# How to automatically make if condition javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
I need to do long list of "if-statement" in javascript, about 700.
```

Is it possible to do without making each condition like list below of three conditions. I need to change value of variable minutes adding "15" and make variable adding every "15". Don't ask me why I have to make so much if-statements. I just wonder if I can do it without making every "value of 15" "if-statement".

```
if (minutes == 124415999040)
                {

            var a;
            a= "480";

        }; //first

 if (minutes == 124415999055)
                {

            var a;
            a= "495";

        }; //second

 if (minutes == 124415999070)
                {

            var a;
            a= "510";

        }; //third and so on up to 700...
```

Comment: A hint: there are multiplication `*` and addition `+` operators available in JS

Comment: I have to ask anyway. What's wrong with doing `var a = minutes - 124415998560`?

Comment: I cannot use "var a = minutes - 124415998560" because it's date-timepicker and it changes value of minutes depends on time you pick time. For example I pick start 11:45pm and close 12:45am and gives different value than the same duration 11:30pm and 12:30am.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I assume a logic where every minute is stored the time in the variable `captureMinutes`

```
var initialMinutes = Date.now();
var captureMinutes = initialMinutes;
var a = 480;
while(1 === 1){
    captureMinutes = Date.now();
    if (captureMinutes.getMinutes() - initialMinutes.getMinutes() === 15){
        initialMinutes = captureMinutes;
        a += 15;
    }
}
```

This is logic. Adapt it according to your logic.

Comment: Got your point, but I got the variable "minutes" from datepicker and to transform this variable "minutes" to variable "a" which I can use further in next functions, I figured out this "if-statements". OK. I will try.